# Why do my lights keep flickering in my unity 2d game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, flicker, lighting

I placed 9 Point Lights within my 2D game on unity, however they keep flickering and not showing when I run the game and in editor, I don't know what's happening, I've tried changing the z value but that doesn't work.

Here is a video as I am horrendous at explaining things.

[Lighting Issues Video](https://vimeo.com/464596900)

I'm relatively new to unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming few Scenarios like you are using latest updated Shaders.

There are few possibilities I think you could give it a try.

**Solution 1:**

This could be because of Z Buffer problem usually caused due to camera clipping values.

> Try Adjusting, by increasing the near clipping plane on your camera or decreasing it.

**Solution 2:**

Check if the Lights placed are not overlapping, sometimes the lights overlapping also may cause flickering,

Comment: That's brill thanks I think it was the size of them so I reduced them but upped the intensity.